# C# WPF: Как использовать 2 разных шрифта в одной строке TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется строка c числом формата `[Целая часть],[6 знаков]`. Пример: `15,555333`

Нужно как-то в параметре `<TextBlock Text="15,555333"/>` сделать часть `15,` с 14 размером шрифта, а оставшуюся `555333` с 10 размером.

До этого делал подобное на `QT`, там в строку просто подставляется `HTML`-код с указанными шрифтами. Соответственно, при подстановке значений можно просто вставить их внутрь кода через форматирование строки.

```html
<html><head/><body><p><span style="font-size:14pt;">15,</span><span style="font-size:10pt;">555333</span></p></body></html>
```

Результат должен выглядеть как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как такое можно сделать в `xaml`-разметке?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например, так:

```xml
<TextBlock><Run FontSize="14pt">15,</Run><Run FontSize="10pt">555333</Run></TextBlock>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]